# Outlook add-in failed to read attachment path

Tags: c#, path, vsto, attachment, outlook-addin

I am trying to obtain the attachment path before a mail is sent from outlook. However when I try so, the result `null`. Here is my code:

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
    }

    void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
    {

        Outlook.MailItem mail = Item as Outlook.MailItem;

        var atts = mail.Attachments;

        foreach (Outlook.Attachment attachment in atts)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(attachment.PathName); // the PathName is null !
        }
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

The user creates a new mail and adds attachments which is already on hard-disk. How can I obtain the path information of the chosen files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That information is not stored in Outlook. On the low level (extended MAPI) the attachment does not even have to come from a file. Imagine a file is dragged from another Outlook message - there is no physical file at all.

Why does the path matter?

Comment: Before sending an email, I wanted to upload the actual file to FTP and replace it with a link. I did it, however I had to save the attachments (temporarily) again to upload them. I was just wondering if I could directly upload the attachments without any saving done...

Comment: No, you can't do that. Even if the user dragged a file, it might be gone by the time the message is sent. In MAPI you can directly access PR_ATTACH_DATA property (open it as IStream), but the performance hit saving file (Attachment.SaveAsFile) is negligible compared to sending the data over the network.

Answer (score 0):

The [PathName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff861856(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Attachment class returns a string representing the full path to the linked attached file. **The property is only valid for linked files.** Check out the [Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff865601.aspx) property value.

The attachment is a copy of the original file and can be accessed even if the original file is removed. I.e. the original file path is not stored with the attached file.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the path name property, however this does not answer my question. It`s more like a comment.

Comment: You may consider adding a custom property to the attachment object when the file is attached.

Comment: How can I obtain the file path when attaching it ? Can you please provide an example of a property you have mentioned ?